# I can't make or receive calls on my IPhone 5c iOS 8.1

Tags: iphone, ios, cellular-carriers

I have a new problem with my iPhone 5c, I can't make any calls from it, but when I use my SIM on other phone it has no problem, and when I put another SIM it can't receive calls either, so obviously the problem is the phone itself. What can I do? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Apple Support: [If you can‘t make or receive calls on your iPhone](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204027)

> **Check your iPhone settings**
>
> 1. Turn airplane mode on and off. Tap Settings > Enable Airplane Mode, wait five seconds, then turn airplane mode off.
> 2. Check your Do Not Disturb settings. Tap Settings > Do Not Disturb.
> 3. Check for any blocked phone numbers. Tap Settings > Phone > Blocked.
> 4. See if Call Forwarding is turned on. Tap Settings > Phone > Call Forwarding.
>
> **Update your software**
>
> 1. Check for a carrier settings update.
> 2. Check for an iOS software update. Some updates might require a Wi-Fi connection.
>
> **Remove and reinsert your SIM card**
>
> If your iPhone has a SIM card, remove the SIM card, then reinsert it.
>
> **Contact your carrier**
>
> When you contact your carrier, check the following:
>
> - Your account is set up to use your iPhone.
> - There aren't any localized service outages.
> - Your account doesn't have a billing-related block.
> - Your calls don't have errors on the carrier system.
>
> **Check your network settings**
>
> 1. Reset your network settings. Tap Settings > General > Reset > Reset Network Settings. This will erase all current saved settings, including Wi-Fi passwords, preferred networks, and VPN settings.
> 2. Try to make or receive calls in another location.
> 3. Switch to a different network band. Tap Settings > Cellular and turn off Enable LTE, 4G, or 3G (this option will depend on your carrier and device model).
>
> **Still can't make or receive calls?**
>
> If you still can't make or receive calls, restore your iPhone as new. If restoring doesn't fix the issue, contact Apple Support or take your iPhone to an Apple Retail Store or Authorized Service Provider.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to restore your iPhone to factory settings and completely wipe the software. Make sure you back up everything you need, e.g. your photos or contacts, since everything will be overwritten during this process. Then make sure you have the latest version of iTunes installed on your computer, if you have a Windows Machine, search for "Apple Software Update" in your Applications, or download the latest version of iTunes from the Apple Homepage https://apple.com/itunes. On a Mac you'd just have to check "Software Update" (in the Apple menu at the top left) until OS X 10.6., or the App Store (from OS X 10.7). Then connect your device, open it in iTunes and click "Restore Firmware". It will do a complete software update, follow the onscreen instructions, and everything should be fine afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me with new phone. I turned it off and back on and it is fine.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

My iPhone 5 was not receiving or making calls and I noticed that my TTY was turned on (phone icon in top right corner). I turned TTY off by going to Settings > General > Accessibility > TTY. You will need to turn off both Software and Hardware TTY buttons. My phone had also somehow (we will not speculate how) got International Roaming turned on and I never travel outside the country, and no children have been playing with my phone. But I turned this off by going into Settings > Cellular > Cellular Data Options > Turn off Roaming/International Roaming.

The combination of these two things fixed my iPhone 5 and I can now call and be called. There was no unusual activity on my phone or no one playing with it when all of a sudden one day I woke up and my phone wouldn't call out or get calls. After 36 hours of searching and reading and resetting and a million other things nothing worked but this. Again, still don't know how they got turned on but they are now off.